# How can I use django-haystack search facets with custom attributes?

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack, django-oscar

I have a Django-oscar shop and I successfully installed Solr 4.7.2 as search engine. It works great with the predefined attributes, e.g. upc, title, product_class...

But filtering for additional attributes did not work.

Thats my catalogue/models.py:

```
class Product(AbstractProduct):
    video_url = models.URLField()
    co2 = models.IntegerField()
    is_public = models.BooleanField()
    test = models.TextField()
```

In search_indexes.py, I tried to add something like:

```
co2 = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr="co2", null=True, indexed=False)

def prepare_co2(self, obj):
        return self.apps.get_model().objects.filter(co2="2")
       # return obj.co2 etc. here I tried a lot of code, but didnt work
```

I also tried to copy the ready-made code for this function.

Has anyone an idea, how to do that? When I filter for catalogue.products.title it works fine but not with cataolgue.products.co2 (which I have suplemented myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my django-oscar version. I updated it and now I can successfully reindex the schema.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can't filter objects from within the prepare function, there you only need to specify how haystack can access the object field.

```
from haystack import indexes
import oscar.apps.search.search_indexes as oscar_search_indexes


class ProductIndex(oscar_search_indexes.ProductIndex):
    co2 = indexes.IntegerField(null=False, indexed=True)

    def prepare_co2(self, obj):
        return obj.co2
```

Above should work (once you've reindexed your products after updating the Solr schema.xml), if not, update your question with the error you get or the unexpected query behavior with sample data.